# Google Script - UrlFetchApp.fetch: post request in Cyrillic windows-1251 charset, how to?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Script to perform search on some domain through post request using UrlFetchApp library, but there is one problem, google script uses UFT-8 charset, but my domain accepts only windows-1251 encoding, and I can't change code on server side.

There is my code:

```
  var url2="http://job-test.1gb.ua/posttest.php";

  var name = "Ультраблиск";

  var form = {"sci" : "iev", "gsearch" :  name };
  var options = {contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1251", 
     "method" : "post", "payload" : form};

  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options).getContentText("windows-1251");

  Logger.log(html);
```

And what I get on server side is "РЈР»СЊС‚СЂР°Р±Р»РёСЃРє" (in windows-1251).

I found out how to read answer in windows-1251, it makes this part - .getContentText("windows-1251");
But post request is always sent in UTF-8 charset.
I was trying to use some JS functions to decode from UTF-8 to windows-1251, like this:

```
var DMap = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99, 100: 100, 101: 101, 102: 102, 103: 103, 104: 104, 105: 105, 106: 106, 107: 107, 108: 108, 109: 109, 110: 110, 111: 111, 112: 112, 113: 113, 114: 114, 115: 115, 116: 116, 117: 117, 118: 118, 119: 119, 120: 120, 121: 121, 122: 122, 123: 123, 124: 124, 125: 125, 126: 126, 127: 127, 1027: 129, 8225: 135, 1046: 198, 8222: 132, 1047: 199, 1168: 165, 1048: 200, 1113: 154, 1049: 201, 1045: 197, 1050: 202, 1028: 170, 160: 160, 1040: 192, 1051: 203, 164: 164, 166: 166, 167: 167, 169: 169, 171: 171, 172: 172, 173: 173, 174: 174, 1053: 205, 176: 176, 177: 177, 1114: 156, 181: 181, 182: 182, 183: 183, 8221: 148, 187: 187, 1029: 189, 1056: 208, 1057: 209, 1058: 210, 8364: 136, 1112: 188, 1115: 158, 1059: 211, 1060: 212, 1030: 178, 1061: 213, 1062: 214, 1063: 215, 1116: 157, 1064: 216, 1065: 217, 1031: 175, 1066: 218, 1067: 219, 1068: 220, 1069: 221, 1070: 222, 1032: 163, 8226: 149, 1071: 223, 1072: 224, 8482: 153, 1073: 225, 8240: 137, 1118: 162, 1074: 226, 1110: 179, 8230: 133, 1075: 227, 1033: 138, 1076: 228, 1077: 229, 8211: 150, 1078: 230, 1119: 159, 1079: 231, 1042: 194, 1080: 232, 1034: 140, 1025: 168, 1081: 233, 1082: 234, 8212: 151, 1083: 235, 1169: 180, 1084: 236, 1052: 204, 1085: 237, 1035: 142, 1086: 238, 1087: 239, 1088: 240, 1089: 241, 1090: 242, 1036: 141, 1041: 193, 1091: 243, 1092: 244, 8224: 134, 1093: 245, 8470: 185, 1094: 246, 1054: 206, 1095: 247, 1096: 248, 8249: 139, 1097: 249, 1098: 250, 1044: 196, 1099: 251, 1111: 191, 1055: 207, 1100: 252, 1038: 161, 8220: 147, 1101: 253, 8250: 155, 1102: 254, 8216: 145, 1103: 255, 1043: 195, 1105: 184, 1039: 143, 1026: 128, 1106: 144, 8218: 130, 1107: 131, 8217: 146, 1108: 186, 1109: 190}

function UnicodeToWin1251(s) {
    var L = []
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        var ord = s.charCodeAt(i)
        if (!(ord in DMap))
            throw "Character "+s.charAt(i)+" isn't supported by win1251!"
        L.push(String.fromCharCode(DMap[ord]))
    }
    return L.join('')
}
```

But what i get on the server side is: "Г“Г«ГјГІГ°Г ГЎГ«ГЁГ±ГЄ" in windows-1251 (and "Óëüòðàáëèñê" in UTF-8) and all other decoding functions what I found did the same.

Comment: have you found the solution? i´m having similar problems.

Comment: No, I didn't find solution for this